# TFS in Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, ssms-2012

I got a project which includes both a windows service (a C# project/solution in VS2013) and some SQL scripts (a SQL Server Script project/solution in SSMS 2012).

Both of these use TFS as source control.

The strange thing is that pending changes differ between VS and SSMS.

- In SSMS I only see changes to files in the SSMS solution.
- In VS I see all changes in both solutions except new files added to the SSMS solution.

This means I can't check in all changes in one place and have them in one change set (unless I manually add the new SSMS files in the VS Source Control Explorer).

I am pretty new to TFS (coming from Mercurial/Git) so I still don't understand how many things work, e.g. how pending changes/source control explorer detect new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TFS 2012 or later, you can choose either a local or server workspace from within VS. There are pros and cons to each but with the local workspace you should be able to achieve this requirement. Visual Studio will detect new files that is within it's source control and add/edit/delete as a pending change as required.

What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems like the TFS plugin for SSMS does not support local workspaces. Do you mean I should treat the skripts as not version controlled in SSMS and handle everything from VS?

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned that you wanted your changes in the same changeset. I have always used VS for my script version control. Wasn't even aware that you could do it in SSMS so maybe I'll check that out for myself too!

Comment: I didn't switch to local workspace earlier since it isn't supported in VS2010 and SSMS. After your reply I investigated it further and found that it works exactly as I want it. Turned of TFS in VS2010 and SSMS and switched to a local workspace. Works very well with automatic detection and **no readonly files** :-) Thanks